# How Do I Add Subviews to an NSTableHeaderCell?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nstableheaderview, nstableheadercell

I have been experimenting with customizing `NSTableView`s and have gotten onto `NSTableHeaderView` and `NSTableHeaderCell` now.

I have a simple need. Each `NSTableHeaderCell` I want to plant my custom view onto. Which simply consists of two buttons.

Here is some code:

I have an `NSTableHeaderCell` category which simply changes the background color with and without highlight.

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(cellFrame, NSCompositeSourceAtop);
}

-(void)highlight:(BOOL)flag withFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [[NSColor greenColor] setFill];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(cellFrame, NSCompositeSourceAtop);
}
```

Next, I have an `NSViewController` subclass, named `NSTableHeaderViewController`. This has a xib which I put my buttons into.

Lastly, in my main view, I set the `NSTableHeaderView` with specified custom height, and add my buttons view to it.

```
APTableHeaderViewController *tableHeaderVC = [[APTableHeaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"APTableHeaderViewController" bundle:nil];

NSTableHeaderView *tableHeaderView = [[NSTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 120, 88)];

[tableHeaderView addSubview:tableHeaderVC.view];
[self.tableView setHeaderView:tableHeaderView];
```

This works partly as expected, creating my 120 pixel high table header with blue backgrounds, green on highlighting. However it only adds my buttons view, `NSTableHeaderViewControlelr`, once in the header at 0, 0.

I kind of expect this, but what is the difference between the header view and header cell?

Also, if I want my buttons view to be in each cell, how can I add it to each?

Thanks.